# integer field select list with min and max value

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to have integer field that ranges from 0 to lets say 100000 with "select list" widget. It doesn't have to have keys i just don't want to type 10000 numbers in field settings of "List integer" field. If I select integer field type it offers min and max but there is no option to have "select list" widget. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://drupal.org/project/range) suits you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with creating these options in Excel with simple 
`B1=A1+1`
and then copy and paste that column - works well

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best way to do this, but it might work for you... you can set up the field as a list and leave it empty, then use a PHP script to populate it, EXAMPLE being your field name:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
      // Get the field info
      $info = field_info_field('field_EXAMPLE');
      // Get a reference to the values
      $values = &$info['settings']['allowed_values'];
      // Manipulate the values in some way, e.g.
      $values[$i] =  $i;
      // Save the field
      field_update_field($info); 
}
```

Then you should be able to see the value listed under your field's values (under admin/structure/content/types/YOURAPGETYPE/fields). You can also use this in the future if you need to add more values, just remove/modify the for loop. I can't take credit for this code, I found it here on SE but just can't remember where.

Comment: clever. i was trying to avoid custom php as it seems such an obvious function to have.

Comment: took 4min to create 500 options with that script. Works but very poor performance

Answer (score 0):

Where can I put that code? Is it in hook_form_alter?

This is for to turn a text field into a drop down on view.

Can be seen here for the ages from and to:

[age to and from drop down needed: can be seen at www.vuxi.com](http://www.vuxi.com)